# cs6servicemanager.exe application error

Tags: windows-error-reporting, adobe-cs6

This is a screenshot of cs6servicemanager.exe when you open it in Dependency Walker.

[image: cs6 service manager screenshot]

There is this application I read about, also here in *superuser* or *stackoverflow*, it's working but real question is;

How am I suppose to know what to do next after I see these errors?